# How to rewrite a URL in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, url-routing

I have this url http://example.com/Book/Details?Bookid=15 this url

I want rewrite url like this http://example.com/Book/Details/BlackBook/

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail in your question.  I think you're actually asking 2 questions here. 1. How to replace the lookup by bookId with the bookName, and 2. how to change the URL to something like this: /book/details/{bookIdentifier}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following route to your global.asax.cs RegisterRoutes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Book By Name",
            "Book/Details/{bookName}",
             new { controller = "Book", action = "BookDetails" }
        );
```

And you'll need a `BookController` with the following Action method:

```
public Book BookDetails(string bookName)
{
    // Your logic here to get a book by name and return it
}
```

Alternatively you can use the default route and create a `Details(string id)` action method within a `BookController` to achieve the same result